# MongoDB Aggregate combine two lookups?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So my schema is split between nodes and links. The links collection has documents like

```
{src: A, dst:B, value:int}
```

and the Nodes collections has

```
{name:A, ...other info}
```

I'm trying to aggregate information for nodes to find sent vs received value data with only one aggregate funciton.

My aggregate function looks like

```
{
 "$lookup":{
    "from":"links",
    "localField":"name",
    "foreignField":"dst",
    "as":"recv"
   }
},
{
 "$lookup":{
     "from":"links",
     "localField":"name",
     "foreignField":"src",
     "as":"sent"
 }
},
```

then I just use a `$project` to sum up the sent/recv arrays for value, resulting in

```
{name:A, sent_value:x, recv_value:y}
```

This works okay, but I noticed that if I took away one of the lookups, the runtime significantly decreases. I'm looking for a way to potentially combine both lookups into one stage of the pipline.
I can very well just issue two aggregations for sent and recv separately, but I want to see if it's possible to only use one aggregate.
Thanks

*Edit*: Example data

```
Nodes: {name: "A"}, {name: "B"},{name: "C"}

Links: {src: "A", dst: "B",value:25}, {src: "A", dst: "C", value:3}, {src: "B",dst: "C", value:19}
```

I want from an aggregation, with what I described above:

```
{name: "A", sent:28, recv: 0}, {name: "B", sent:19, recv:25}, {name: "C",sent:0,recv:22}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @ray I added in sample data that gives the gist of what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one single `$lookup` to get all dst and src data at once. Then, use `$reduce` to perform conditional sum on the array.

```js
db.nodes.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "links",
      let: {
        name: "$name"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $or: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$name",
                    "$src"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$name",
                    "$dst"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "linksLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      name: 1,
      recv: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$linksLookup",
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            "$add": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$cond": {
                  "if": {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.dst",
                      "$name"
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": "$$this.value",
                  "else": 0
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      sent: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$linksLookup",
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            "$add": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$cond": {
                  "if": {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.src",
                      "$name"
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": "$$this.value",
                  "else": 0
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PfXuHKag8i3) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for the playground, it's helping me understand what's going on in your code. I had a hunch I had to do the correlated subquery in lookup, but wasn't sure where to go from there.